# Send bulk email using Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

In the app I'm creating a user will be able to send a description of an object to a number of recipients (from 1 to 200). Using Parse Cloud Code I'll have to use a promise to wait for the email server response for every email (Mailgun).

Is there any other way where I stock all those created emails in some kind of array and send them in 1 shot to the email server? Otherwise I hit the max of 15 seconds a function can run.

Right now I use this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("emailobject", function(request, response) {

// ... some company info parameters
var theTraders = request.params.traders;

var objectQ = new Parse.Query("objects");
objectQ.equalTo("objectId", theObjectId);
objectQ.first({
    success:function(theObject) {
        // ... more code
        searchObjectPictures(theObject, {
            success:function(pictureObjects) {
                for (var a = 0; a < theTraders.length; a++) {
                    // create the parameters to create the email
                    var mailingParameters = {};
                    // ... create the parameters

                    // when the email html has been compiled
                    mailgun.sendWelcomeEmail({
                        to: traderEmail,
                        from: toString,
                        subject: subjectString,
                        html: mailing.getMailingHTML(mailingParameters)
                    }, {    
                        success:function(httpResponse) {
                            console.log(httpResponse);
                        }, 
                        error:function(httpResponse) {
                            console.log(httpResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
                 // emailedObjectsToSave is an array of analytics objects
                Parse.Object.saveAll(emailedObjectsToSave, {
                    success:function(list) {
                        response.success(true);
                    }, 
                    error:function(error) {
                        response.error(error);
                    }
                });
            },
            error:function(error) {
                response.error(error);
            }
        });
    },
    error:function(error){
        response.error(error);
    }
});
});
```

I know promises would be better for nested queries, but I'm still wrapping my head around this.

Thank you

Comment: The key is `Parse.Promise.when()` which takes an array of promises and returns a single promise that is fulfilled when all of the passed promises have been fulfilled.  Have your maligun function answer a promise (don't supply completion handlers), call it in a loop and fill an array with those promises.

Comment: @danh I'll try that. Thanks! Got any idea about the time out?

Comment: The only option is a scheduled job that runs on a short frequency and does a smaller batch, picking up where the last run left off.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, trial and error, I have finally found the solution. As @danh said it's better to add these requests to a job queue. The objects are now saved to a "notifications" class that has a bool "notified" to check if this object has already been sent or not.
I'll post the code here for people who might also search for it.

First you add your objects to the new "notifications" class (queue).

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addToNotificationsQueue", function(request, response) {

    var roleName = request.params.role;
    var objects = request.params.objects;

    var newEmailObjectsToSave = [];
    var EmailedObjectClass = Parse.Object.extend("notifications");

    var emailObjectACL = new Parse.ACL();
    emailObjectACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
    emailObjectACL.setRoleReadAccess(roleName, true);
    emailObjectACL.setRoleWriteAccess(roleName, true);

    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        // define the parameters for the new objects based on the request params

        var emailObject = new EmailedObjectClass();
        // set all the details to your new emailObject
        emailObject.setACL(emailObjectACL);
        newEmailObjectsToSave.push(emailObject);
    }

    Parse.Object.saveAll(newEmailObjectsToSave, {
        success:function(list) {
            response.success(true);
        }, 
        error:function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Then define your job. I run it every 15 minutes for now to test. When the mailserver starts acting faster, I'll set the limit and frequency higher.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("sendNotifications", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var numberOfNotificationsHandled;
    var query = new Parse.Query("notifications");
    query.limit(10); // limit because max 15 minutes, slow email server...
    query.notEqualTo("notified", true);
    query.find().then(function(notifications) {

        numberOfNotificationsHandled = notifications.length;

        var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

        _.each(notifications, function(notification) {

            var parameterDict = {};
            // add all parameters the emailObject function needs

            promise = promise.then(function(){
                return Parse.Cloud.run("emailObject", parameterDict).then(function(result) {
                    notification.set("notified", true);
                    notification.save();
                }, function(error) {
                    notification.set("notified", false);
                    notification.save();
                });
            });
        });

        return promise;

    }).then(function() {
        console.log("JOB COMPLETED");
        status.success("Sent " + numberOfNotificationsHandled + " emails");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("JOB ERROR " + error);
        status.error("Job error " + error);
    });
});
```

The emailObject method is just an httpRequest like any other. This method waits for the answers of those httpRequests.